# Uninstalling OS X applications and associated configuration files

Tags: macos, uninstall

When I first bought a computer with OS X (Yosemite) I was ecstatic to see how simple the uninstall was (just drag the application to the trash). However, I soon thereafter found out that it actually just deletes the application but all the remaining configuration, preferences, and other files that the program creates still remain. This is great for upgrades as you can just physically drag and drop an app to upgrade (i.e. replace the original application) and all your configuration files remain.

However, being the paranoid person I am, I want to be able to remove *all* files generated by a program in some cases.

Do I have any options for this, or do I just have to go off on the whims of the developer? I know there are some uninstaller programs but they don't seem to work completely.

In Windows for example, I know there was an app called Sandboxie which allowed me to make a little sandbox which kept track of everything that was made. Maybe there's an equivalent for mac? or maybe there's some other tools that might work.

What's your thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a few KB of leftover prefs, really.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of third-party apps that can achieve this, such as (for example) [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). They search for additional configuration files in *typical* locations (i.e. `~/Library/Application Support`, `~/Library/Preferences`, etc.).

Some applications do not install all their files in the typical locations that these app uninstallers search in. In those cases, you may need to do a case-by-case search to determine which files you need to manually remove.

Comment: Yes, I use AppCleaner and I think it works great!

Comment: Thanks. I've seen app cleaner before but it was really the case in the second paragraph that I was wondering about. Maybe one way that would work is if there was a way to check changes to the FS from a moment. I could then run the program and see what was installed since I took my initial 'snapshot'. Do you know any program that would facilitate this?